# Android Coroutines on firestore?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, solid-principles

I am trying to implement the SOLID principle inside of an APP. Regarding the single responsibility of each class, can coroutines be used together with `firebase firestore`? if Yes, how can I listen inside `ViewModel` when the query is finished?

Example:

```
class CampaignsViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    private val greenService: GreenService,
    @Assisted private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
): ViewModel() {

    fun getCampaigns() {
        greenService.getCampaigns()
    }
}


class GreenServiceImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val db: FirebaseFirestore,
) : GreenService {

    override fun getCampaigns() {
        db.collection(FirestoreDatabases.CAMPAIGNS.name)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                for (document in it) {
                    Log.d(BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE, "${document.id} => ${document.data}")
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {

            }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you are trying to do but not being too familiar with the firestore api you could do something like this I believe

in `GreenServiceImpl`

```
suspend fun getCampaigns() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
    val task = db.collection(FirestoreDatabases.CAMPAIGNS.name).get()
    val result = Tasks.await(task)
    //Do something with the task result
}
```

then in vour ViewModel

```
fun getCompaings(){
    viewModelScope.launch {
        greenService.getCampaigns()
   }
}
```

Adjust as needed but a rough idea of what you can do.

You could also use `suspendCoroutine` if you want to return something

```
suspend fun getCampaigns():SomeResult? = suspendCoroutine{
    val task = db.collection(FirestoreDatabases.CAMPAIGNS.name).get()
    val result = Tasks.await(task)
    it.resume(result)
}
```

or even use `Flow` with `callbackFlow` https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html